# Maximum of 2 Thumbnails on a configurable product page

Tags: thumbnail

I am using Magento CE 2.1. I have a configurable product with 3 pictures. I can only get 2 thumbnails on the screen under the main picture. The thumbnail pictures (under the main product image) will alternate between all three color pictures. I cannot get all three pictures on the screen at the same time. How can I fix this?

Thanks